# Realsense LiDAR - What exactly does the infrared stream depict and what is it's exploitation value?

Tags: computer-vision, lidar, infrared, realsense

**TLDR**: Since RS L515 is not a multi-spectral camera, what is the reason of providing an infrared stream, and what can it be used for?

[image: Depth stream (left) | Infrared stream (right)]

---

I have just purchased a RealSense L515 camera, and I have noticed that an infrared stream is also depicted in the viewer. At first, I got excited, since I thought that apart from visible range, the camera also captures wavelengths in the NIR (even though I didn't spot such feature in the specs when purchasing), and then I saw that even thought it does, it is actually not **(see Note 1)**. After reading the [official datasheet](https://dev.intelrealsense.com/docs/lidar-camera-l515-datasheet), it is mentioned that the **IR stream represents the intensity of the reflected IR laser reflected off the objects in the scene**.

##### Basic background

L515 accomplishes Laser-scanning by using pulses of laser at 860 nm, and *receives the infrared reflections* **(see Note 1)** to construct the 3D cloud, according to the timed delay between transmission and reception (see [Time of Flight](https://www.intelrealsense.com/beginners-guide-to-depth/)).

##### Personal assumption

It is reasonable to assume that depending on the material of each surface that exists within the captured environment **(see Note 2)**, the intensity of the transmitted IR pulse is affected upon reflection, so supposing that this is what IR stream actually depicts, **what is it useful for?** Is it for providing a certainty value of the corresponding pixel's depth information (i.e. low intensity pixel => low reflectance => poor depth quality)? Another assumption is that, if it is simply used for clustering objects with different texture for assisting depth estimation, why is it provided as a separate stream anyway?

Is there anyone that could shed some light on it?

##### Notes

**(1)** (update) As for the reflected light, it uses a [MEMS Mirror optical board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microelectromechanical_systems) for capturing. In contrast to hyper-spectral sensors, this sensor processes the receiving light of **the same wavelength-range** - that is around 860nm.
**(2)** in fact depending on the reflection coefficient of an object's surface which may be strained by it's texture or color